# scons cannot import numpy module

Tags: python, numpy, scons

I have a sconstruct file and i am trying build a process.

A part of my code is below.

```
# Import modules needed by Scons
import os
import sys

# Create an Scons Environment
env = DefaultEnvironment()
env.Decider('MD5-timestamp')

sys.path.append(r"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages")
sys.path.append(r"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy")
sys.path.append(r"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg")
import numpy
```

When i try to run scons, it complain about not able to find some sub module of numpy such as lapack_lite, _umath_linalg. The screenshot of the error attached.

I have checked this files inside my site-pacages. It is defintely present inside the folder.

When i import numpy library from python, i dont have any problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a dependency issue.

The only solution that worked was to completely remove python, all its libraries.

Reinstall python, libraries and scons back. Made sure all pythonpath and sys path are set properly.

It started to work